# The extension of functions

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

Let $f$ be a smooth function defined on $[a,b]$ and $g$ a smooth function defined on $[c,d]$. If $a<b<c<d,f'(x)>0, g'(x)>0$ and $f(b)<g(c)$, then can we find a function $h: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ which is a diffeomorphism of $\mathbb R$ such that $h=f$ on $[a,b]$ and $h=g$ on $[c,d]$?

Comment: Could you please, specify what you mean by a smooth function on a closed interval. There are two alternative definitions and with one you get the positive answer and with the other you get the negative answer to your question.

Comment: @studiosus By smooth function $f$ on $[a,b]$ I mean there is a $\delta>0$ such that we can find a smooth function $\phi$ defined on $(a-\delta,b+\delta)$ and $f=\phi$ on $[a,b]$.

Comment: OK, then it will work: I assume you are also requiring that $f'(x)>0, g'(x)>0$ for all points of the closed intervals where these functions are defined.

Comment: I will write a detailed proof when I have a bit more time.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof. I will construct an extension only to the interval $[b,c]$ but the same argument will work for the other two complementary intervals. By pre- and postcomposing with invertible affine functions, I will  assume that $b=0, f(b)=0, c=1, f(c)=1$.

Let $V$ denote the space of all $C^\infty$ functions $g$ on $[0,1]$ such that $g^{(i)}(0)=f^{(i+1)}(0), g^{(i)}(1)=f^{(i+1)}(1)$ and $g(x)>0$ for all  $x\in [0,1]$. The  space $V$ is convex. Also,
$$
0=\inf_{g\in V} \int_0^1 g(x)dx, \quad \infty= \sup_{g\in V} \int_0^1 g(x)dx.$$
(Let me know if you need help verifying these properties.)

Therefore, by continuity of integral and convexity of $V$, there exists 
$g_1\in V$ such that $\int_0^1 g_1(x)dx=1$.

Now, define the extension of $f_1$ to $[0,1]$ by the formula:
$$
f_1(x)=\int_0^x g_1(x)dx.
$$

Then $f_1(0)=0$ (clear), $f_1(1)=1$ (since $\int_0^1 g_1(x)dx=1$). By the construction, $f_1$ is a $C^\infty$ extension of $f$ to $[0,1]$. Since $f'(x)>0$ for all $x\in [a, d]$, the extension gives a diffeomorphism (to its image) $[a,d]\to {\mathbb R}$.